# Is there a good resource that would help to estimate and compare travel expenses by city?

Tags: budget, online-resources, planning

I am looking for a resource with somewhat accurate/reliable estimations of travel expenses for popular tourism destinations. I am able to find bits and pieces on wikitravel, tripadvisor, lonelyplanet guides and elsewhere. However, a more exhaustive and organized resource would be much more helpful for all the travelers planning their budget and weighing their options.

budgetyourtrip.com resembles to what I am looking for, but I am not too convinced of the accuracy of their data: according to it, daily expenses in Paris are in average 50% higher than daily expenses in Oslo.

So, it there an obvious and well-known resource that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2):

Something more for expats but along this line is Expatistan.

For example: Comparing [Sydney, Australia to Christchurch, New Zealand](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living/comparison/sydney/christchurch).

It looks at thousands of data points submitted by users, and produces stats on transportation, food etc.

While housing may not be that useful to you, it at least gives you a good reference point for the other aspects of existing in that city.

Comment: Numbeo.com is similar to expatistan (in fact, I suspect one of them started as a copy of the other).  But it might be a useful comparison.  I'm not so sure of their numbers, though.  Both told me to expect to pay three to five hundred pesos a month for a one bedroom apartment in Monterrey, Mexico.  Looking at advertisements online, I conclude one to two thousand pesos a month is a better number.